# How many ways are there to pick $r$ objects from $n$ objects when repetitions are allowed and either both the first and second...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to pick $r$ objects from $n$ objects when repetitions are allowed and either both the first and second objects appear exactly once or both do not appear?

I'm pretty sure that this is a choosing problem, and I understand that the first part is $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$, but I have no idea how to do the second part ("either both the first and second objects..."). Where do I go from here?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please explain what you have tried and where you are stuck so that you receive answers that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first two objects appear exactly once: We choose these two objects and then we must choose $r-2$ of the remaining $n-2$ objects with allowed repetitions. So we have $\binom{n-2+r-2-1}{r-2}=\binom{n+r-5}{r-2}$ by stars and bars.

If the first two objects don't appear at all: We choose $r$ objects of the remaining $n-2$ objects with allowed repetitions. So we have $\binom{n-2+r-1}{r}=\binom{n+r-3}{r}$ by stars and bars.

Since there is no overlap between these possibilities, we use the sum rule to get our final answer: $$\binom{n+r-5}{r-2}+\binom{n+r-3}{r}$$